I want to know how should I send the VesionedTransaction to the user for signature?
export async function sendWcVerTransaction(
  signClient: Client,
  session: any,
  transaction: VersionedTransaction
) {
  const message = transaction.message;
  const addressTableLookups = message.addressTableLookups;
  const addressLookupTableAccounts = await Promise.all(
    addressTableLookups.map(async (lookup) => {
      return await getAddressLookupAccounts(lookup.accountKey);
    })
  );

  const transactionMessage = TransactionMessage.decompile(message, {
    addressLookupTableAccounts: addressLookupTableAccounts,
  });
  const data = {
    chainId: "solana:5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdp",
    topic: session!.topic,
    request: {
      method: "solana_signTransaction",
      params: {
        feePayer: transactionMessage.payerKey!.toBase58(),
        transaction: transaction.serialize(),
      },
    },
  };
  // console.log("----------------------------");
  // console.log(data.request.params.instructions);
  console.log("----------------------------");
  const result = await signClient!.request<{ signature: string }>(data);
  return result;
}

I hope to send the versionedTransaction to the connected user through walletconnet's SignClient for signature, but the above signature method does not seem to be able to take effect.
export async function signWcMessage(
  signClient: Client,
  session: any,
  transaction: VersionedTransaction,
  owner: PublicKey
): Promise<any> {
  const result = await signClient!.request<{ signature: string }>({
    chainId: "solana:5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdp",
    topic: session!.topic,
    request: {
      method: "solana_signMessage",
      params: {
        message: bs58.encode(transaction.message.serialize()),
        pubkey: owner,
      },
    },
  });
  return result;
}


But it is available if I directly serialize the message carried by VersionedTransaction.
I want to know how should I send the VesionedTransaction to the user for signature?
